# On ipad swipe view one over another like sound cloud app

Tags: ipad, soundcloud

I have created side tab bar in view controller and added a table view on tab on item of tab bar. main problem is i want to swipe a view which comes after tab on cell of table like as popover comes on it in full view. Now i want to slide ( you can say swipe over another view) just like happen in sound cloud application . What should i use to design like that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: help me out there is requirement of making app design same as sound cloud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is quite simple just use the cocoa control frlayerednavigationcontroller you get sample code here....
https://github.com/weissi/FRLayeredNavigationController
how it works shown in video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_tXD_mL05E